# Wordpress can't write to file

Tags: wordpress, apache, permissions, file-permissions, chmod

I've moved my wordpress installation from a managed VPS to a new centos server.
Now I've a problem with writing to files directly from the wordpress admin panel.

Folders/files are set with 755/644. User owner is "wwwuser", group is "apache" (I use this one to access to the documentroot via ftp).

I think that the problem is that in `/etc/httpd/conf/http.conf` I've user and group setted both to "apache", in fact everything works if I change permissions to 775/664, which should mean that when the group owner is setted to apache everything work, right?

So my question is, should I change all permissions to 775 or there's another solution, which doesn't lead to security issues? Is it safe to make all folders and files 775 and 664? What if I change "apache" to "wwwuser" from `/etc/httpd/conf/http.conf`?

Edit: is it possible that the problem is that in phpinfo, environment pwd is set to `/home/wwwuser/test` and not to `/home/wwwuser/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise to not change the user Apache is running under (to not edit the Apache config file) but to set `apache` as the owner of the files. 
`chown -R apache /path/to/your/app/files`

I think it's the easiest solution. If you choose to change the permissions, you shouldn't have to change the permissions for everyone (other): you could change to 774 but I don't see why 775.

By default Apache is running under the `apache` user on CentOS.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The problem is that I could use FTP in future (e.g. to upload plugins), and this can cause problems because ftp is associated with wwwuser. What will happen also if I automatically download e plugin from wordpress ui? How can it be possible that in my previous VPS I didn't had any of this problem, and user owner was not apache?

Comment: @daimpa If the plugin files you upload don't need to be edited by php, then it should work. If they do, then you may have to change the owner. If you download a plugin from Wordpress, it will be working as `apache` will create the files on the server. There are various reasons explaining why it was working in your previous VPS: web server configuration, files permission...

Comment: Aussourd: thanks once again for your reply and your patience. In the old server files permissions was the same, 755/644. Do you think that it'll be extremly hard to create the same environment regarding the owners? I mean, I've been trough many shared hosting, and I never had this problem. Now I'm on a dedicated server, and would like to do things in the correct way..

Comment: @daimpa On shared hosting, they probably set Apache to run under different users corresponding to different customers. That would explain why it was working. I deployed many php websites (including a couple of Wordpress websites) and I always had to be sure Apache had the permissions and I never had security issues. Wordpress security advices:  http://www.copyblogger.com/wordpress-website-security/ Concerning your VPS, make sure SSH access is restricted (I advise to deactivate root login and only accept ssh key authentication). You can also take a look at fail2ban to protect your server.

Comment: I've just tested to install a new plugin from wordpress UI... It asked for FTP username/password, so it used the user wwwuser and the group apache for the file, with permissions 755 for files and folder, so that's not good. It should have used apache user, or 775 :(

Comment: @daimpa Did `apache` have file permissions? If you don't give permissions to Apache to the files/folder that Wordpress needs to edit, Wordpress will ask you for the owner credentials http://www.limecanvas.com/how-to-stop-wordpress-asking-for-ftp-details-to-upgrade-plugins/

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem you are facing right now. Some times files/directories created/uploaded with FTP may have been assign a different users/usergroup. As @Céline Aussourd stated, if you have installed plugin from WordPress then all files and directories will get the default user/usergroup.

Now easiest way to identify which user should be assigned to your files is create a single test file using CPanel file manager called "test.php" and access it from web if it is working then check its user/usergroup and change all your setup files to that user/usergroup all together with

```
chown -R {user} /path/to/your/worpress/root
```

Replace {user} with apache web user.

**UPDATE: (To install plugin without FTP details)**

Please add following line to your wp-config.php after **define('WP_DEBUG', false);** line.

```
define('FS_METHOD', direct);
```

Remove plugin and re-install it, this time it wont ask you for FTP details and will write files directly.

Comment: it asked me for FTP user/password when trying to install a new plugin from wordpress UI, so it created all files/folders with user wwwuser and group apache, with permissions 755, which is wrong, it should have been user apache or permissions 775...

Comment: Can you remove plugin for re-install? If yes please follow my updated answer above.

Comment: It worked by setting apache as both user/Group owner like said by celine. I did it before but I don't know why it didn't saved.

Comment: Great! Still in future if you want to install plugin without FTP keep my last update ;)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to add the mod_suexec apache module